# Singular cohomology module of a space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Spanier's AT theorem 5.4.10,

> The singular cohomology module of a space is the direct product of the singular cohomology modules of its path components.

In the book, the reason is : If $\{X_i\}$ is the set of path components of $X$ then $\Delta(X) = \bigoplus_j\Delta(X_j)$ so $Hom(\Delta(X);G)\simeq\prod_jHom(\Delta(X_j);G)$. And as on the category of chain complexes the homology functor commutes with sums and with products, the result follows.

I don't understand why 'as on the category of ...' proves the theorem. The relation between homology and cohomology introduced so far is just obtaining cochain complex from chain complex by reversing the sign and vise versa. Could you explain this?

Answer (score 2):

A cochain complex is obtained from a chain complex not by reversing the sign but by applying $Hom(-,G)$ functor componentwise. In other words, if $\ldots \to C_i \to C_{i+1} \to \ldots$ is your chain complex, the chain complex for cohomology ("cochain complex") is going to look like $\ldots \to Hom(C_{i+1}, G) \to Hom(C_{i}, G) \to \ldots$

What Spanier says is that since the cochain complex for $X$ is the product of cochain complexes for $X_j,$ the same relation will hold for cohomology, because the two operations $-$ 1. taking quotients of cycles over boundaries of a chain complex 2. taking componentwise product of chain complexes $-$ commute.